# Indentify consecutive cells by a condition value

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to make an extra column on the below dataframe that will be 1 when on the age column are 3 or more consecutive values bigger than 35

Data

```
age
0   12
1   50
2   49
3   29
4   55
5   34
6   23
7   46
8   87
9   39
```

desired output:

```
   age  flag
0   12     0
1   50     0
2   49     0
3   29     0
4   55     0
5   34     0
6   23     0
7   46     1
8   87     1
9   39     1
```

How could I do that? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First compare values by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for `>`, then create consecutive groups by `shift` with `cumsum`, last grouping by groups and get counts with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) - compare by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and chain with original `s` for prevent set 3 consecutive `>35` values, last set values to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
s = df['age'].gt(35)
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

df['flag'] = (s.groupby(g).transform('size').ge(3) & s).astype(int)
print (df)
   age  flag
0   12     0
1   50     0
2   49     0
3   29     0
4   55     0
5   34     0
6   23     0
7   46     1
8   87     1
9   39     1
```

Comment: One more question, what if I would have a index with hours (%Y%m%d %H%M%S) and I would like to get the 1 wher age > 35 on 2 cnosecutive days ?( consider that index date is increased by 1h?

Comment: @Capie - Is possible create new question? Because not easy answering with no data.